# Routing another EDIT & UPDATE function in Laravel9

Tags: laravel

I'm studying routing at Laravel9

I'm trying to add another EDIT and UPDATE page. so I wrote this.

pool.blade.php

> When User want to change record ownership click below link then
> process.

```
<td><a href="{{route('blogs.change_ownership', $blog->id)}}">{{$blog->id}}_I will change ownership</a></td>
```

Controller

```
    public function change_ownership(Blog $blog)
{
    return view('blogs.change_ownership',compact('blog'));
}

public function update_ownership(Request $request, Blog $blog)
{
    $blog->br_name      = $request->br_name; //changer ownership A to B

    $blog->save();
    return redirect(route('blogs.index'))->with('status', 'ownership_changed_sucessfully');
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/blogs/pool/{blog}', [BlogController::class,'change_ownership'])->name('/blogs/change_ownership');
Route::post('/blogs/change_ownership/{blog}', [BlogController::class,'update_ownership'])->name('/blogs/change_ownership');
```

Currently I got this error

> Route [blogs.change_ownership] not defined.

Could someone teach me correct code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dot notation in your route names, as you are already doing in your blade file. Try to change:

```
Route::get('/blogs/pool/{blog}', [BlogController::class,'change_ownership'])
    ->name('/blogs/change_ownership');
Route::post('/blogs/change_ownership/{blog}', [BlogController::class,'update_ownership'])
    ->name('/blogs/change_ownership');
```

to

```
use App\Http\Controllers\BlogController; 

Route::get('/blogs/pool/{blog}', [BlogController::class,'change_ownership'])
    ->name('blogs.change_ownership.edit');
Route::post('/blogs/change_ownership/{blog}', [BlogController::class,'update_ownership'])
    ->name('blogs.change_ownership.store');
```

In pool.blade.php you can refer to the edit route:

```
<td><a href="{{route('blogs.change_ownership.edit', $blog->id)}}">{{$blog->id}}_I will change ownership</a></td>
```

Also make sure your controller is defined correctly, with the correct namespace and class name, like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class BlogController extends Controller 
{
    public function change_ownership(Blog $blog)
    {
        return view('blogs.change_ownership',compact('blog'));
    }

    public function update_ownership(Request $request, Blog $blog)
    {
        $blog->br_name = $request->br_name; //changer ownership A to B

        $blog->save();
        return redirect(route('blogs.index'))
            ->with('status', 'ownership_changed_sucessfully');
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear @piscator Thank you very much for helping me. I tried you code then I can display pool.blade.php Thank you. but. When I click the link which change_ownership I got this error.
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: You're welcome. I missed one detail, the route names should be unique. Try to add `.edit` and `.store` to the route names. Of course now you would also need to change the name in the route method in your blade view. See updated answer

Comment: Thank you very much for keep helping me. I learned many things thank you! I replace code. but when I click the link I got this error Target class [BlogController] does not exist.

Comment: Make sure your class is defined correctly, and that you imported the class in your route file. I've added details in the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you and Sorry I skipped basic things. I appreciate you have been helping me. I replace code but still I got error. Route [blogs.update_ownership] not defined.  I tried to fix myself this time but I... it's still hard for me. sorry.

Comment: Perhaps you have a form where the method refers to `route('blogs.update_ownership', $blog->id)`? Please change this to `route('blogs.change_ownership.store', $blog->id)`

Comment: Thank you. I replace the code. now I got Route [blogs.change_ownership.store] not defined.

Comment: Dear @piscator Thank you very much for helping me. please take your time. sorry to say this I have to leave this place so I will contact you tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I learned a lot of your code. but this time I will use actually edit function. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm happy I could be of help!